# Ruby parse string and return array

Tags: ruby, string

I have input string `str ="/Users/user/Desktop/task/U6342_Account_20150112.txt"`

and in return I want array `['U6342','Account','20150112']`

To get the result what I did

```
str.split('/')[-1].gsub('.txt','').split('_')
```

which outputs `['U6342','Account','20150112']`

Now my question- Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby has a built-in File class for similar cases.

```
fname = File.basename(str, '.*') # "U6342_Account_20150112"
fname.split('_') # ["U6342", "Account", "20150112"]
```

Or, in short:

```
File.basename(str, '.*').split('_')
```

**Edit:** the second parameter in `basename` tells the function what suffix the file has. It supports the `*` wildcard to match any suffix, and then removes it from the result. Examples:

```
File.basename(str, '.*') # "U6342_Account_20150112"
File.basename(str, '.txt') # "U6342_Account_20150112"
File.basename(str, '.jpg') # "U6342_Account_20150112.txt" => suffix not removed
```

Read more here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-basename

Comment: ".*" what does it means?